# Network cannot connect to server c# unity5

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

I've done Network C# script in unity5.
It's based on https://vimeo.com/33996023 
Everything goes good until 30min of tutorial.
I did build, run it, start server in a build, then in unity start game, refresh hosts, 1 server pop up, i click on it and nothing happens then i get message: Failed to connect to 10.0.0.100:25001 because this system is already connected. This can occur when the network connection is disconnected too quickly for the remote system to receive the disconnect notification, for example when using Network.Disconnect(0).

My script:

```
public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public string gameName = "DP_Network_server";
    private bool refreshing;
    private HostData[] hostList;


    void OnGUI() {

        if (!Network.isClient && !Network.isServer) {

            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 10, 150, 100), "Start Server")) {
                Debug.Log ("Starting Server");
                startServer ();
            }   

            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 200, 150, 100), "Refresh Hosts")) {
                Debug.Log ("Refreshing");
                refreshHostList ();
            }

            if (hostList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < hostList.Length; i++) {

                    GUI.Button (new Rect (400, 100 + (110 * i), 300, 100), hostList [i].gameName);
                    Network.Connect (hostList [i]);

                }
            }
        }
}

void startServer() {
    Network.InitializeServer(32, 25001, !Network.HavePublicAddress());
    MasterServer.RegisterHost(gameName, "Double Planet Game", "This is test of networking");
}

void OnServerInitialized()
{
    Debug.Log("Server Initializied");
}

void OnMasterServerEvent (MasterServerEvent mse) {
    if (mse == MasterServerEvent.RegistrationSucceeded) {
        Debug.Log ("Registered Server");        
    }
}

void refreshHostList() {
    MasterServer.RequestHostList(gameName);
    refreshing = true;
    }

void Update (){
    if (refreshing) {
        if (MasterServer.PollHostList().Length > 0) {
        refreshing = false;
            Debug.Log (MasterServer.PollHostList ().Length);
            hostList = MasterServer.PollHostList();

        }

    }

}
```

}

I did set in project settings>player play in background and i attached network view to Player. Is something wrong with Network.Connect (hostList [i]);?

Answer (score 0):

well,I think there is a reason that when Client start to connect to the Server but not finished, it will continue try to connect every frame,you can make it just did that once. 
maybe you can change it as this:

void OnGUI() {

```
    if (!Network.isClient && !Network.isServer) {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 10, 150, 100), "Start Server")) {
            Debug.Log ("Starting Server");
            startServer ();
        }   

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 200, 150, 100), "Refresh Hosts")) {
            Debug.Log ("Refreshing");
            refreshHostList ();
            if (hostList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < hostList.Length; i++) {

                GUI.Button (new Rect (400, 100 + (110 * i), 300, 100), hostList [i].gameName);
                Network.Connect (hostList [i]);

            }
       }
     }
 }
```